# In statistical mechanics, why do we consider number of states of a system in energy interval?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

In statistical mechanics,when we go for calculating the no. of accessible micro states of a system, I notice that we always calculate the no. of micro states of that system in some energy interval say between $E$ and $E+dE$ instead of calculating the no. of micro states at particular energy $E$. Even,in micro canonical ensemble,in order to calculate the entropy of a system we use the renowned formula $$S=k \ln W$$
where $W$ is the number of accessible micro states of the system in energy interval between $E$ and $E+dE$ but not the micro states at energy $E$. So my question is why we always calculate micro states in enery range $dE$, but not at a particular energy $E$ of the system?

Comment: Please don't shout at us.

Comment: If I randomly pick a number between 0 and 1, what is the probability that it will be, say, 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer***

*I prefer the notation $E+\Delta E$, because I want it to be clear that we are talking about a finite quantity (i.e. nowhere we will take the limit $dE \to 0$ or such things).*

**Theoretical point of view**

You can surely consider the states with energy precisely equal to $E$ and define the microcanonical probability density as

$$\rho(p,q) = C \cdot \delta(H-E)$$

where $C$ is a constant and $H=H(p,q)$ is the Hamiltonian. This is for example what Landau does in his book.

However, it can be shown that for large $N$ this definition is equivalent to

$$\rho(p,q)=C' \cdot \int_{E<H<E+\Delta E}d^{3N}pd^{3N}q$$

for a suitable constant $C'$ and for some constant $\Delta E$, which doesn't even necessarily be "small" (see for example my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268598/115736), or Tuckerman's book).

**Experimental point of view**

There will always be some uncertainty on the measurements you can effectuate of the system's energy. If you want, this $\Delta E$ represents this uncertainty.

Therefore, while from a mathematical point of view it makes perfect sense to take $\delta(H-E)$ as your probability density, form an experimental point of view it makes much more sense to consider energies in some finite interval.

**Addendum about entropy**

If all you want is to calculate the entropy, things get even "easier". Indeed, the high dimensionality ($6N$) of phase spaces makes it so that you can equivalently define the entropy as

$$S = k_B \log \int_{E<H<E+\Delta E}d^{3N}pd^{3N}q$$

$$S = k_B \log \int_{H<E}d^{3N}pd^{3N}q$$

or even

$$S = k_B \log \left( \partial_E \int_{H<E}d^{3N}pd^{3N}q\right)$$

where $\partial_E$ is the partial derivative with respect to $E$.

The difference between these definitions will be a constant of order $\log N$ or smaller, irrelevant since $S$ is of order $N$ (see Huang, *Statistical Mechanics*).

Comment: @pragyanpratimbordoloi If this answer solved your doubt, you can consider accepting it.