# Unit of number of microstates $\Omega(E)$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, partition-function

The definition of the entropy is :

$$S=k_b \ln(\Omega(E))$$ for a system that has energy $E$ fixed.

But when we look at the definition of the number of accessible microstates, we have :

$$ \Omega(E) = \int \frac{dp dq}{h}\delta(E-H)$$ that has the unit of the inverse of an energy.

But we write it inside of a logarithm in the definition of the entropy, thus it should be unitless.

Thus, there is something I don't totally understand.

Can we define $\Omega(E)$ with a Dirac delta like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [number of states in microcanonical ensemble](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268440/)

Comment: I think you are missing something because the delta function has units of inverse the argument.  If $q$ and $p$ are the canonical position and momentum, then your result has units of inverse energy.  I am guessing the arguments in the delta function are normalized (i.e., unitless)?

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost an exact duplicate of [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268440/number-of-states-in-microcanonical-ensemble).

However, long story short is that the correct definition is

$$ \Omega(E) = E_0 \int \frac{d^{3N}p d^{3N}q}{h^{3N} N!}\delta(E-H)$$

where $E_0$ is an arbitrary constant with the dimensions of energy whose value has no influence on the thermodynamic quantities. Also notice that I included the factor $N!$ for the correct Boltzmann counting.

For more details, see the linked question.

Comment: This definition is arbitrary, because $E_0$ is arbitrary. The very reason for dividing by $h^{3N}$ is to get a value of number of states that does not depend on choice of units like classical phase volume does. So if there is $E_0$, it should have a definite value, not arbitrary value.

Comment: Maybe $\Omega(E) = E \int \frac{d^{3N}p ~d^{3N}q}{h^{3N}N!} \delta(E-H)$.

Comment: @JánLalinský In the continuum, the "number of states" doesn't really make sense. So you either define a "number density of states" (with dimensions $1/E$) or you choose some way to normalize the density to get a dimensionless number so you can take a logarithm. This normalization shouldn't matter in the end since we're always interested in changes in the entropy in thermodynamics.

Comment: I always thought the "integration over phase space" was a bit of a hack to try to get a statistical-mechanics-like counting argument in a continuous classical theory. If you do a counting of states quantum mechanically in a situation where the number of states is actually finite (like a particle in a box) you can actually calculate the normalization. I'm not sure offhand what happens if you try to take a limit of a particle in a box where the box becomes infinite (getting back to a continuum of states), maybe you get some kind of infrared divergence.

Comment: @Andrew Actually, there is a way to define number of states even for continuum of possible states, e.g. via restriction to psi functions that have nodes on the box walls; the possible psi functions are from a continuous space and there is uncountable infinity of them, but the number of states is a different concept, because only eigenfunctions count.

Comment: I agree the normalization/dimensionality isn't a practical problem in practical calculations in thermodynamics and one can work with phase space volume in SI units (a surprisinly small number even for macroscopic volume of gas) or its density on the energy axis. But the reason we introduce $h$, $N!$ and aim for dimensionless $\Omega$ is to get a unique number that is somehow more close to the real nature of things, so stating $E_0$ is arbitrary defeats that very purpose and then introducing $h$ or $N!$ is pointless.

Comment: @JánLalinský Introduction of $N!$ is a different story. It is required to get an extensive entropy. Definition without Dirac's delta requires an unspecified constant $H$ to make the volume element in phase space dimensionless. Dirac delta requires a constant $h'$ with different dimensions, but the role is the same. It may be convenient to write as $E_0/h^{3N}$. Using $E$ in the place of $E_0$ is impossible because the Laplace transform of $\Omega$ should give the canonical partition function.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I agree (except it's really Laplace transform of $d\Omega/dE$). In case of ideal gas with $E\geq 0$, this argument about the partition function implies $E_0 = k_BT$ (which is not arbitrary).

Comment: @JánLalinský No, we are working the the microcanonical ensemble and $T$ would be a function of $E$. The value of $E_0)$ is ra true arbitrary constant with the dimension of an energy. The real reason it is allowed to introduce such an arbitrary constant is that statistical mechanics formulas give the thermodynamics only at the thermodynamic limit. In such a limit, the presence of the *constant* $E_0$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 You're right, $E_0=k_BT$ leads to wrong result, I made a mistake. But when I calculate mechanically (interchanging order of integration) partition function as Laplace transform of density of states function:  $\int_0^\infty d\Omega/dE e^{-\beta E} dE$ - with $\Omega$ depending on arbitrary constant $E_0$(independent of $E$ or $T$) - I get the wrong result $Z=\beta E_0 Z_{correct}$ as well, where $Z_{correct} = \int \frac{d^{3N}qd^{3N}p}{h^{3N}N!} e^{-\beta H}$.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I've re-formulated my qualms with this in a new question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/788745/what-is-the-number-of-quantum-states-compatible-with-ideal-gas-macrostate-n-v-t /